# Filter a JSON in base of a radius coordinate

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I need to filter a JSON with an array of places with their coordinates, in base of user, coordinates. the way I found was use a loop to traversing an array and to the user's coordinates I added 0.05 to this coordinates and if place coordinates was between user's coordinates and user's coordinates + 0.05 return that place.

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it works for me. Here I leave an example.

```
const filterTotems = (userCoordinates) => {
    const filtredTot = [];
    totems.map((tot) => {
      if (
        (inRange(tot.latitude, userCoordinates.latitude, userCoordinates.latitude + 0.15) &&
          inRange(tot.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude + 0.15)) ||
        (inRange(tot.latitude, userCoordinates.latitude, userCoordinates.latitude - 0.15) &&
          inRange(tot.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude - 0.15))
      ) {
        filtredTot.push(tot);
      }
      return true;
    });
    setFiltredTotems(filtredTot);
    return true;
  };
```

I use the function inRange of lodash.

I need an other opinion about that and if is an other way to do it

Comment: `map`+ `push` is sort of an anti-pattern. Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

Comment: You're checking all the values twice. You could check if the latitude is between the userCoordinates + .15 and -.15: `inRange(tot.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude - 0.15, userCoordinates.longitude + 0.15)`

Comment: And instead of `inRange` you could just do `if (Math.abs(tot.latitude - userCoordinates.latitude) < 0.15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is better suited for what you're trying to do. By returning a boolean, you can control which elements of the array are kept without the need for creating a new array manually.

It also looks like you could have a bug in your code where you're only searching two of the four quadrants around the user's coordinates. It's possibly overkill to be using lodash for this too, we can do this in vanilla JS. All of the above combines to make the following result:

```
const filterTotems = (userCoordinates) => {
  const filteredTotems = totems.filter((tot) => {
    const latOffset = Math.abs(tot.latitude - userCoordinates.latitude);
    const lonOffset = Math.abs(tot.longitude - userCoordinates.longitude);
    return (latOffset < 0.15) && (lonOffset < 0.15);
  });

  setFiltredTotems(filteredTotems);
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @JJ Gray for your comment it really works for me!